# Can flexdashboard see the global environment?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, knitr, flexdashboard

Im tying to use a function to generate plotly charts within flexdashboard.

````
---
title: "Single Column (Fill)"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---
  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(plotly)

```
### Chart 1

```{r}

pltFunction(x,y)

```
````

If i click the green arrow, which says "run current chunk", the function works and plots the graph underneath the code chunk.

However, if i click knit, i get:

> Error in pltFunction(x,y)  :    could not find function "pltFunction"
>   Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible ->
>   eval -> eval

I'm very new to shiny et al, apologies for the simple question here, but can flexdashboard see the global environment? The function and all the data it needs are there.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to have the values `x` and `y` created in the document.

Comment: the code that generates x and y is quite large. Is there anyway to bring it in cleanly? Can knitr solve this?

Comment: Put the code that generates x and y in a `script.R`, save it,  and call it with `source("script.R")` from inside the chunk.